# OWL2 property reference OWL2 Class

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology, dbpedia

I would like know if it is possible to use a property to point to a class.
Im'm trying to build a sport ontology, and I'm trying to use parts of DBPedia ontology to enrich mine. 
My sports ontology has a class Surf, and I am trying to create a property to associate this Surf class to the DBPedia Beaches class.
I'am trying to achieve that with a property isPracticedAt, somehthing like:

Surf :isPracticedAt DBpedia:Beaches.

Doing some research, it seems that this class to class property is not possible. I did not wanted to create a property isPraticedAt in the Surf class to all the beaches present in the DBPedia ontology, as it would be impractical.

Are there anyway I could say that Surf isPraticedAt any DBpedia:Beaches?

My real goal was to get all the individuals of the class pointed by isPraticedAt, and then filter by distance(DBPedia:Beaches has lat and long). Is this possible in any way?

Comment: There are various ways you can achieve that. The best would be just to use a SPARQL query, and get all individuals of dbpedia class "Beaches" with their geo data, and then, assuming you have geo data for individuals of you class "Serf", filter by distance. An alternative would be if you get those Dbpedia individuals locally, then you can use reasoner for a small set. If you give some data and example of the expected result, you'll get a better chance of a useful answer.

Comment: The first question is why Surf is a class in your ontology? Are there multiple instances of this class? Second, you can make use of OWL punning, that allows to use the same URI for both, a class and an individual

Comment: @AKSW youre right about representing Surf as class, It doesn't make much sense, I will change it to an instance of Water Sport or something like that. thanks.

Comment: @IvoVelitchkov thank you for your answer, I will try to make myself clearer.

Lets say I have class Sport with individuals _Surf_ and _Sailing_. I also have a class called _Lake_ with individuals _LakeA_ and _LakeB_ and a class _Beach_ with individuals _BeachA_ and _BeachB_. I wanted to have a property to say _Surf_ praticedAt _Beach_ and _Sailing_ praticedAt _Lake_, so I could use a SPARQL query to fetch all _Beach_ individuals when dealing with _Surf_, and all _Lake_ individuals when dealing with _Sailing_

Comment: @AKSW Just tried your suggestion of using punning and It worked out great! Thank you!